# Prove that $\inf\{d(x,y):x\in\pmb S_1, y\in\pmb S_2\}$ is in the set.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let the distance of two subsets $\pmb S_1$ and $\pmb S_2$ of a given complete metric space $(X, d)$ be defined as $d(\pmb S_1,\pmb S_2)=\inf\{d(x,y):x\in\pmb S_1, y\in\pmb S_2\}$.
Suppose that $\pmb S_1=\{x\}$ and $\pmb S_2$ is closed.

Prove $d(\pmb S_1,\pmb S_2)=d(x,y)$ for some $y\in\pmb S_2$.

In my opinion, if $d$ is not specified, how would I know whether the infimum is in the set or not because proving a set being closed involves $d$.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: @Shashi A convergent sequence in a closed set must converge to a cluster point in the closed set. I know this but how I can prove that this set is closed?

Comment: Take $S_2=\varnothing $. It's close and $d(S_1,S_2)=+\infty $.

Comment: @H.Zhu sorry I think my comment was  misleading

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then the distance will be attained. For the proof consider $y \in \pmb S_2$ and $\pmb S_2^\prime = \pmb S_2 \cap \{z \in X \mid d(x, z) \le d(x,y)\}$. $\pmb S_2^\prime$ is compact and therefore $d(x ,\pmb S_2)$ is attained.

For an infinite dimensional vector space, the distance may not be attained. Consider $\pmb S_2 = \mathcal c_0$ the vector space of real sequences converging to zero equipped with the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ norm. The hyperplane $H= \{(x_n) \in \mathcal c_0 \mid  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} x_n =0\}$ is closed as it is the kernel of a continuous linear form. However for $a \notin H$, $d(a,H)$ is not attained.

For the proof, you can look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/distance-between-a-point-and-a-hyperplane-not-reached/).